# Sort elements of a list with two or more criteria

Tags: python, sorting

I have the ZZ tuple for 3 lists that each includes 7 lists. I would like to sort ZZ for each of three lists use descending order for the first element. If two first elements have the same values, I would like to first do descending order for them based on their differences. Second, if one of these lists has more cost give it priority.
In the following you can see the lists:

```
ZZ= [[[500, 475], [500, 1307], [1500, 1476], [500, 537], [0, 527], [500, 452], [1000, 446]], [[350, 475], [700, 1307], [1050, 1476], [0, 537], [350, 527], [350, 452], [700, 446]], [[400, 475], [1200, 1307], [1200, 1476], [200, 537], [400, 527], [400, 452], [800, 446]]]
Cost=[600, 110, 35, 110, 200, 120, 80]
```

my code is:

```
YY=sorted(enumerate(ZZ[s-1]),key=lambda x: ( x[1], -x[0]), reverse=True)
index_list= [b[0] for b in sorted(enumerate(ZZ[s-1]),key=lambda x: ( x[1]),   reverse=True)]
```

the results of this code is:

```
YY = [(2, [1500, 1476]), (6, [1000, 446]), (1, [500, 1307]), (3, [500, 537]), (0, [500, 475]), (5, [500, 452]), (4, [0, 527])]
```

However I would have the following list:

```
YY = [(2, [1500, 1476]), (6, [1000, 446]), (0, [500, 475]), (5, [500, 452]), (3, [500, 537]),  (1, [500, 1307]), (4, [0, 527])]
```

Comment: Why would you like 500,1307 end up last of your 500-series? Because it starts with a 1? Can't figure out the logic you're after. 475, 752, 537, 1307 doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort a list based on more than one criteria, you can do this with a lamda function that returns a tuple

A small example:

```
ZZ= [[500, 475], [500, 1307], [1500, 1476], [500, 537], [0, 527], [500, 452], [1000, 446]]
YY = sorted(ZZ,reverse=True,key=lambda y: (y[0],y[0]-y[1]))
```

`y[0]` ist the first value and `y[0]-y[1]` is the difference. If you want to bring in a second list (Cost) you can combine the two lists and (if you need it) the position.

```
ZZ= [[500, 475], [500, 1307], [1500, 1476], [500, 537], [0, 527], [500, 452], [1000, 446]]
Cost=[600, 110, 35, 110, 200, 120, 80]
ZZc=[ZZ[z]+[Cost[z]]+[z] for z in range(len(ZZ))]
print(ZZc)
```

prints

```
[[500, 475, 600, 0], [500, 1307, 110, 1], [1500, 1476, 35, 2], [500, 537, 110, 3], [0, 527, 200, 4], [500, 452, 120, 5], [1000, 446, 80, 6]]
```

and now you can sort it with

```
YY = sorted(ZZc,reverse=True,key=lambda y: (y[0],y[0]-y[1],y[2]))
```

or if you want to sort 1. Value 1, 2. Cost and 3. Difference you can sort it with:

```
YY = sorted(ZZc,reverse=True,key=lambda y: (y[0],y[2],y[0]-y[1]))
```

to get the list of tuples in your question the script would be like:

```
ZZ= [[[500, 475], [500, 1307], [1500, 1476], [500, 537], [0, 527], [500, 452], [1000, 446]], [[350, 475], [700, 1307], [1050, 1476], [0, 537], [350, 527], [350, 452], [700, 446]], [[400, 475], [1200, 1307], [1200, 1476], [200, 537], [400, 527], [400, 452], [800, 446]]] 
Cost=[600, 110, 35, 110, 200, 120, 80]

YY=[]
for Zi in ZZ:
    ZZi=[Zi[z]+[Cost[z]]+[z] for z in range(len(Zi))]
    YY.append(sorted(ZZi,reverse=True,key=lambda y: (y[0],y[2],y[0]-y[1])))

for Yi in YY:
    print([(y[3],[y[0],y[1]]) for y in Yi])
```

My original answer befor I knew that you can sort with tuples (it works but don't use ist):

You can sort it with

```
ZZ= [[[500, 475], [500, 1307], [1500, 1476], [500, 537], [0, 527], [500, 452], [1000, 446]], [[350, 475], [700, 1307], [1050, 1476], [0, 537], [350, 527], [350, 452], [700, 446]], [[400, 475], [1200, 1307], [1200, 1476], [200, 537], [400, 527], [400, 452], [800, 446]]] 
Cost=[600, 110, 35, 110, 200, 120, 80]

for Zi in ZZ:
    ZZi=[Zi[z]+[Cost[z]]+[z] for z in range(len(Zi))]
    YY = sorted(ZZi,reverse=True,key=lambda zlist: (int(zlist[0])*1000000)+(int(zlist[0]-zlist[1])*1000)+zlist[2])
    print [(y[3],[y[0],y[1]]) for y in YY]
```

Comment: @ Leonhard thanks for your reply, there is an error for this code:\\ print [(y[3],[y[0],y[1]]) for y in YYn] 
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: If you use python 3 you have to add parentesis. You can test it on: http://rextester.com/TQJQ66828

Comment: As you mentioned Nr 0 should come before Nr 5 as well

Comment: @ Leonhard, the first problem is fixed, thanks a lot!

Comment: Why? The difference is less

Comment: You are right but the cost is more, I should put cost as the first criteria. But it is fine thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @ Leonhard sorry again! I am beginner in Python. How can I put every YY [ZZi] in a separate list?

Comment: $ Leonhard is there any way to give priority to Nr 0  to Nr 5?

Comment: I made an update to my answer so that it is easier to understand. http://rextester.com/TMH79701